# VB.NET Simplify Action(Of T)

Tags: vb.net, lambda, refactoring

I am using VB.Net 4 and am successfully using a class with the following signature:

> Sub Register(Of TMessage)(recipient As Object, action As
>   System.Action(Of TMessage))

I want to learn about lambdas in VB so I wanted to see if I can simplify my current code.

CURRENTLY: I have the following in the constructor of a class (simplified for clarity)

```
Public Sub New()
    Dim myAction As New Action(Of String)(AddressOf HandleMessage)
    Messenger.Default.Register(Of [String])(Me, myAction)            
End Sub
```

And later in the class I have the following:

```
Private Function HandleMessage(sMsg As String)
    If sMsg = "String Value" Then
        If Me._Selection.HasChanges Or Me._Selection.HasErrors Then
            Return True
        End If
        Return False
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function
```

QUESTION: Is there a way to simplify this into a lambda like in C# where I don't have to declare the MyAction variable in the constructor, but just pass the string value to HandleMessage function "**inline**" with the register sub? (I hope that makes sense)

Comment: man, i'd kinda forgotten how clumsy vb.net stuff is.

Comment: did you write the c# and try running it through a c# to vb converter?

Comment: Dan-o  Yes, but the converters never handle C lambdas properly, sometimes it is way off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So your constructor code is equivalent to:

```
Messenger.[Default].Register(Of String)(Me,
    Function(sMsg)
        If sMsg = "String Value" Then
            If Me._Selection.HasChanges Or Me._Selection.HasErrors Then
                Return True
            End If
            Return False
        Else
            Return False
        End If
    End Function)
```

It's worth mentioning though you don't need to use lambdas just to get rid of your explicit delegate creation. This is perfectly legal too:

```
Messenger.[Default].Register(Of String)(Me, AddressOf HandleMessage)
```

There is a bit of strangeness though with your example: you've declared your Register method as taking an `Action(Of TMessage)` which means the function passed needs no return value. Your function however is returning a `Boolean`. Visual Basic here is doing the fancy "delegate relaxation" and is throwing away the return value. So all your `Return True`/`Return False` bits aren't actually doing anything special.

Comment: Yes thanks, I was trying so many things I forgot about the function vs sub change.  You code worked.  I thought I had tried that but I guess I didn't.